# How to map by similar rows in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

df1 :

| Names | Rs | demand | tax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albert | 486 | 785 | 545 |
| John | 2300 | 30 | 40 |
| jac | 3999 | 70 | 20 |
| joe | 334 | 780 | 10 |
| peter | 34 | 366 | 10 |

df2 :

| Names | Rs | demand | tax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sanjay | 4562 | 7895 | 1231 |
| Sunil | 7896 | 7822 | 89 |
| Peter | 34 | 366 | 16 |
| Shweta | 78 | 785 | 12 |
| John | 2300 | 30 | 18 |

I have two pandas dataframes and some rows of these dataframers are equal
for example, the 5th row in df1 with name `Peter` is the same as the 3rd row in df2. Just tax column is not same. And 2nd row in df1 with name `John` is same as 5th row in df2. Just tax column is not same, I want to change that tax column in df2 and make it same as df1. I tried everything. Can someone please help me here.

here's the code if you want to use this dataframes in your local machine:

```
Names = ['Albert', 'John', 'jac', 'joe', 'peter']
Rs = [486, 2300, 3999, 334, 34]
demand = [785, 30, 70, 780, 366]
tax = [545, 40, 20, 10, 10]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Names':Names,
                   'Rs':Rs,
                   'demand':demand,
                   'tax':tax})



Names = ['sanjay', 'sunil', 'peter', 'shweta', 'John']
Rs = [4562, 7896, 34, 78, 2300]
demand = [7895, 7822, 366, 785, 30]
tax = [1231, 89, 16, 12, 89]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Names':Names,
                   'Rs':Rs,
                   'demand':demand,
                   'tax':tax})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try via `map()` and `fillna()`:

```
df2['tax']=df2['Names'].map(dict(df1[['Names','tax']].values)).fillna(df2['tax'])
```

Output of `df2`:

```
    Names   Rs      demand  tax
0   sanjay  4562    7895    1231.0
1   sunil   7896    7822    89.0
2   peter   34      366     10.0
3   shweta  78      785     12.0
4   John    2300    30      40.0
```